# PHP/SQL Update Field with word if selection matches

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sql-update

I've been looking for a solution to the following but have had no luck so far.

I have a page that has a list of product features in a text area, named "features" - this is populated from a table in my database.

When I click a button the below code is run, what the code does is take each word in my list, checks if the "description" field contains that word and if it does then it puts that word in a field called "features".

This works fine but I have 3,000 different "features" and 100,000 product descriptions to check - so it takes along time to run and often times out.

Can anyone advise how I can speed this up? basically the logic is:

If "description" contains "word" put "word"

I was thinking of maybe putting all of the words in an array but I don't know how to determine which of the words in the array are in the "description" and return this value.

All of the "features" are stored, separated by commas in my desc_lookup table, so these can easily be added to an array.

```
$features = explode("\n",$_POST["features"]);
$features = str_replace("\r","",$features);

foreach($features as $feature)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."products` 
           SET features = CONCAT(features, '".$feature.",') WHERE `description` LIKE
           '%".database_safe($feature)."%'";

    database_queryModify($sql,$result);
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Chris

Comment: Just use fulltext: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Thanks RePRO, could you give me a quick example, i'm new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would do this kind of keyword search when inputting the product into your database and store them as a separate field (Or in another table possibly). Or possibly employ a caching system so you don't have to do it for every single product every time.

Comment: The problem is that these products are imported automatically at night and I don't input them manually

Comment: Is there no way of going through the process of finding the keywords every time a record is inputted during this process? If not, perhaps running a regular task of going through all products that have no features assigned to them can be done daily too? Otherwise, caching might be your best bet I think